# How can i get IP address of systems in a local network which accessing the webpage from local server using php

Tags: php, lan

I have a local network which connected to internet through a proxy server, The proxy server IP address is `192.168.0.1`. All systems in the network assigned IP address manually like 192.168.0-6.1-255 ,Subnet mask 255.255.248.0, `Default gateway 192.168.0.1`

and i created another server in local network for accessing my website locally and its IP address is `192.168.0.25`, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, Default gateway 192.168.0.25

All the systems in the local network can now access the website using the address

`http://192.168.0.25/`

I have to track all the systems accessing my website so i used the function `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`  in php. But i getting the IP address of all system  which accessing my website is as same as the proxy server IP address(`192.168.0.1`).
Please help me to get the correct IP address of each system.

Comment: I have the same issue have u found any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {   //check ip from share internet
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {   //to check ip is pass from proxy
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
```

Comment: To add to this, take a look at how the Symfony HTTP Request object captures this. https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L591

Comment: @Rishi Kalia No I am checking it from different systems in the local network all of them showing the same ip 127.0.0.1. the function $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] is getting this IP. But if i try to access this page from the proxy server it showing its own IP 192.168.0.1 But here the function $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is getting the IP

Comment: @Joseph Paul it's your proxy server or more specifically firewall that is giving you _127.0.0.1_..i have double checked the script and it's echoing me desired results..

Comment: @Rishi Kalia i already Turned off the firewall But may be because of the proxy server. But i need a solution for this, I can't avoid the proxy server  and i cant put the webpage in the proxy server. The both servers should be in separate. Please get me a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRealIpAddr()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))  
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) 
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
      $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}

echo $userIP = getRealIpAddr();
```